How to configure Elastic Beanstalk Enhanced Healthcheck for Springboot
I have a Springboot application that lives in AWS Elastic Beanstalk, and want to make use of the Advanced Healthcheck features where it tracks the responses by status category (2xx, 3xx, 4xx, 5xx). We had hoped that after deploying the more recent implementation of our api that this would happen automatically, but it didn't. I expect that there is going to be some type of logging that needs to be enabled for these metrics to be aggregated, but sadly I've been unable to reach a solution after many more hours of research than I'd like to admit.
The application is deploying into Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.4.5 if it matters.
Been researching this off and on for over two years now, and been unable to find any direction.
